# Is it possible to delete the last property (alphabetically) from an object?

Tags: javascript, object

A property can be deleted like

`delete myObj.myProperty`

or

`delete myObj["myProperty"]`.

But I want to delete the last property from many objects with different names for that property, the only rule is that is the last one in the object.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: what do you mean with *alphabetically*?

Comment: names of properties in alphabetical order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the keys and pop the last one for deletion.

This does not work properly for integer values which could be indices of an array, because this keys are sorted to top, by the actual standard.

```
delete myObj[Object.keys(myObj).pop()];
```

If you want to delete the last key in the alphabet sorting, you could include a sort before popping.

```
delete myObj[Object.keys(myObj).sort().pop()];
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, sort the keys first, than find the last and use it.

```
const [first] = Object.keys(obj).sort((k1,k2) => k1 - k2).reverse();
delete obj[first];
```